# Express route with data in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can I route a data to a location without destroying the current data in the main route?

Example: I have 3 routes:

- a. The post route (main)
- b. The upload route (this is used to upload media files).
- c. The location route (this help user to select their location).

If user go to the upload file and preview a file it will be display in the post (main) page likewise the location.
It is very similar to the old facebook way of posting.

Currently I can make the file preview but if I go to the location page, the file will disappear including the content in the main page.
I am using Jade as my templating engine.
The code is arrange in an MVC structure.

The main page route controller code:

```
 initBlog: (req, res, next) =>{
    let user = req.user._id,
        location = req.query.feeling,
        media = req.query.media;
      res.render('post',{
        title: 'Simple Blog',
        location: location,
        media: media
        content: content
    });
```

The controler for media:

```
 initBlogMedia: (req, res, next) =>{
    let user = req.user._id,
        link= req.query.link,
        media = req.query.media;
    if(media){
        re.redirect(link+'?media=media')
     }
      res.render('post',{
        title: 'Add Media',
        link: link,
        media: media
    });
```

This is just the bare bone because the code can take upto 4 pages.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour (again) and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: In particular... post your coded scripts below your question and related information.. ;-)